# How to show multiple edit text error simultaneously?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to validate text input, but how to show multiple edit text error simultaneously??
Here is my code

```
binding.btnCalculate.setOnClickListener() {
            val panjang = binding.etPanjang.text
            val lebar = binding.etLebar.text
            val tinggi = binding.etTinggi.text


            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(binding.etPanjang.text)) {
                binding.etPanjang.setError("Field must be filled")
            } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(binding.etLebar.text)) {
                binding.etLebar.setError("Field must be filled")
            } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(binding.etLebar.text)) {
                binding.etTinggi.setError("Field must be filled")
            } else {

                val action = InputFragmentDirections.actionInputFragmentToOutputFragment(
                    panjang.toString().toInt(),
                    lebar.toString().toInt(),
                    tinggi.toString().toInt()
                )

                findNavController().navigate(
                    action
                )
            }
        }
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YRjm.png)
I Want all edit text that empty is showing error, not only one edit text

Comment: You should not use ```else if``` and should instead separate them into 3 ```if``` statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change if .. else to if only for each condition so each condition can be checked and set error if input is not valid

replace your code with below

```
binding.btnCalculate.setOnClickListener() {
            val panjang = binding.etPanjang.text
            val lebar = binding.etLebar.text
            val tinggi = binding.etTinggi.text

            var isAnyError = false
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(binding.etPanjang.text)) {
                binding.etPanjang.setError("Field must be filled")
                isAnyError = true
            }else{
                binding.etPanjang.setError(null)
            } 
            
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(binding.etLebar.text)) {
                binding.etLebar.setError("Field must be filled")
                isAnyError = true
            }else{
                binding.etLebar.setError(null)
            } 
            
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(binding.etLebar.text)) {
                binding.etTinggi.setError("Field must be filled")
                isAnyError = true
            }else{
                binding.etTinggi.setError(null)
            }

            if(!isAnyError){
                val action = InputFragmentDirections.actionInputFragmentToOutputFragment(
                    panjang.toString().toInt(),
                    lebar.toString().toInt(),
                    tinggi.toString().toInt()
                )

                findNavController().navigate(
                    action
                )
            }
        }
```